# Which Twitter application does my consumer key belong to?

Tags: twitter

Somebody at my company generated a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret with Twitter some years ago, but I no longer know who. I don't have the application's ID or the Twitter ID of the owner of the application, just the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. (They work fine for authentication purposes.)

Can I use my consumer key and secret to figure out who the application/owner of the keys are?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Settings/Application](https://twitter.com/settings/applications) page of a Twitter account which has authorized the app.  It is possible that the author has linked to his home page from the app description.

Failing that, the information you are looking for is not accessible to anyone other than the creator of the app.

Comment: It's linked to our company's home page. Not really informative. :-(

Comment: In that case, then you're limited to trying to find the original developer.